# Android - Glow Effects on Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, paint, glow

i want to make an Android app and draw on canvas with a glow effects for the circles, squares etc that i draw on it. Much like the application [Art of Glow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.natenai.artofglow).

[Art of glow http://iphonecake.com/appcake/appimg/380120815-0.jpg](http://iphonecake.com/appcake/appimg/380120815-0.jpg)

This is what i have achieved by now and it doesn't seem to have the amount of glow i target i have used BlurMaskFilter() for this.

[image: Mine]

I tried using setShadow() and setShader() but the Glow effect isn't strong enough. If you can help me with this it'd be a great favor and might help other users as well...

regards
Saad.

Answer (score -2):

You could consider creating the image objects you wish to use in your app in [PhotoShop](http://www.photoshop.com/) or [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) with a glowing effect and export them as portable network graphics.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Luke but i want for the drawn objects to be animated like their sizes, radius etc. that's why i can't use images.

Comment: You could still change your image dimensions.

Comment: but the image would get distorted and will lose quality and possibly speed of the animations...

Comment: though i will try out what you suggested.